# Как задать время жизни объекту в DB. Meteor. Mongo

Tags: google-maps-api, mongodb, meteor

Добрый день, подскажите как лучше реализовать задачу. Нужно задать время существования объекта в базе. Например, пользователь создает зону на карте, после чего задает ей имя и может задать время активности этой зоны (1.01.2018 - 2.02.2018).

```
export function EnterName(polygonArray) {
let polygonObject = {};
let polygonType = true;
if (!polygonType)
    polygonType = false;
let polygonName = prompt('Enter location Name');
if (!polygonName)
    EnterName();
else
    polygonObject = {name: polygonName, coords: polygonArray, type: polygonType}
saveZone(polygonObject);
```

Comment: Я, наверное, создал бы функцию, которая проверяла метки на живучесть и запускал ее когда это необходимо.

Comment: А можно реализацию с вашей стороны?

Comment: По сути, в БД нужна только информация о том, когда удалять метку. В нужный момент достаете эту инфо, сравниваете с текущей датой: если наступила - удаляете, если нет, то нет.